# how do i append two nested list into single nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

i have two nested list like:

```
a = [[2,3,4],[3,5,6]]
b = [[4,5], [5,6,7,7,7]]
```

i need to append two nested list into single nested list.

Expected output:

```
[[4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 7, 7], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```

I tried this way,

```
a = [[2,3,4],[3,5,6]]
b = [[4,5], [5,6,7,7,7]]
b.append(a)
print(b)
```

output i got:

```
[[4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 7, 7], [[2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6]]]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Use `extend` method of the `list` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new list:

```py
a = [[2,3,4],[3,5,6]]
b = [[4,5], [5,6,7,7,7]]
c = a + b
# [[2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6], [4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 7, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unpacking is one way of doing it:

```
c = [*a, *b]
# [[2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6], [4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 7, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.extend`, given

```
a = [[2,3,4],[3,5,6]]
b = [[4,5], [5,6,7,7,7]]
b.extend(a)
```

**Note**: the `.extend` method extends the existing list and changes made are in the list on which .extend is performed, so here changes are made to b

**output**:

```
[[4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 7, 7], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```